# Configure node app in azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I have deployed a node app in Azure and want to configure it. This is the content of the file "index.js" that I want to test:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

var cats = [{name:'Lily'}, {name: 'Lucy'}];

var corOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};
app.use(cors(corOptions));
app.listen(3000,() =>{
    console.log('Server started :)');
});
app.route('/api/cats').get((req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.hostname);
    console.log(req);
    res.send(cats);
});
console.log("Server is running...");
```

Here's package.json file

```
{
"name": "app-service-hello-world",
"description": "Simple Hello World Node.js sample for Azure App Service",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"license": "MIT",
"author": "Microsoft",
"engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.1"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
},
"dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3"
}
}
```

web.config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^index.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm testing the application using following below URL but not getting the expected output: https://firstnodeapp1.azurewebsites.net/api/cats

I tested it locally as http://localhost:8000/api/cats and it works fine. So, actually concerned about what's missing.

I would really appreciate any help to configure it properly.

Comment: Can you share your web.config contents? It may be that you are still pointing to the default server.js instead of your setup which is index.js as the start file.

Comment: @RedJandal, I have added the content of web.config file in the question..

Comment: Instead of forcing port 3000 in app.listen can you try process.env.port

Comment: I tried that initially, but it didn’t work, there was an error message saying that port should be between 0 and 65535.

Comment: Have you enabled error logs in Azure to try and identify where the issue is? How did you deploy the node app?

Comment: I deployed using git repo. I haven’t enabled error logs, but l’ll do so and check if I get something.

Comment: @GauravKrishn It's required to use `process.env.port` on Azure, and on my side this project works well using git deploy. Could you offer details about the error you got?

Comment: @JerryLiu, It's working now, I just redeployed the code, using process.env.port, and it worked, but not sure why it wasn't working earlier.

Comment: @GauravKrishn Probably caused by cache. I post a complete answer with details, you could accept it to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change port to `process.env.port` and redeploy your code should work.

Explanation:

Azure Web App is a model of [sand box](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#network-endpoint-listening), which is accessed via the only two already-exposed 80(HTTP) and 443(HTTPS) TCP ports.

Using `process.env.port`, Azure will create a named pipe for your Nodejs server to listen, and pass the request from 443 port to the named pipe. Any specific port inside your app is invalid and will cause Server Internal Error(500).